# Windows Subsytem Linux Inconsistent File I/O Errors

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I've been having some pretty hard to diagnose issues working with WSL, Ubuntu 18.04

**The problem:** Random File I/O failures

**Environment:**

- Windows 10
- WSL: Ubuntu 18.04

**Steps already taken**

- `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
- Grabbed latest updates for Windows 10
- Restarted the machine
- Health-check of the machine's disk
- Ensured that the disk is not nearly full
- Double checked the permissions of the files in question

**The details**

Throughout the process of installing the tools I need on this WSL, I've had strange issues with random files not being written during the apt-get install, and during Yarn install several failures to read files. But when I check those files, they definitely exist, and the permissions are such that the files should be readable.

These are the sorts of problems I'd expect to find with an unhealthy disk, or a nearly-full disk, but neither of those things appear to be the case.

So how can I go about diagnosing and solving this problem? It's pretty consistent - I can run yarn install 10 times and have it fail on-read/write of a different file every time, and sometimes succeed.

**Examples of Errors**

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/c/Users/jamie.butler/projects/swm/web/node_modules/is-extendable/index.js'`

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/c/Users/jamie.butler/projects/swm/web/node_modules/polished/lib/shorthands/margin.js'`

Comment: I've added some examples of errors I'm receiving. After further reading, it seems like I'm having similar experiences as those described in [this MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/). But in my case I'm following the recommendations and working in the mounted directory.

Comment: Just do a `chmod 664 filename; chown $USER filename`, it'll fix the issue.

Comment: As one of the steps I've already taken, I've already assessed the permissions and ownerships of the trouble files. Additionally, the problems come and go. The same lstat against the same file may pass or succeed at different times. My gut tells me that's a file-lock issue, but I don't know how to be sure or how to resolve.

Comment: I have the same problem when I try to run a jest set of tests. Jest tries and resolve dinamically modules on the filesystem, and it keeps failing on different files every run.